Error: Cannot Resolve Symbol '@style/Theme.Androidstudio' in AndroidManifest.xml for Kotlin Android Development
this is the snippet of my AndroidManifest.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Androidstudio"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

I have already checked my project's styles.xml file to ensure that '@style/Theme.Androidstudio' is defined properly, and it does exist. However, Android Studio seems unable to resolve this symbol.
I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, syncing Gradle files, and even restarting Android Studio, but the error persists.
In addition to resolving this error, I'm also seeking guidance on implementing CRUD operations within my Kotlin Android app. Any advice, resources, or examples related to CRUD operations in Kotlin would be greatly appreciated.

Refer to the solution below, I have also provided step by step procedure for implementing the CRUD operations in Kotlin:
CRUD OPERATION WITH SQLITE
Go to AndroidManifest.xml
add these permissions -
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

below  tag and above  tag
like here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Androidstudio"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

}

After the class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
add this line
private lateinit var db:SQLiteDatabase

after the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
add this line
 db = openOrCreateDatabase("employeemanager.db", MODE_PRIVATE,null)

Creating a table
val createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(employeeid INT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, phonenumber INT, country TEXT)"
        db?.execSQL(createTableQuery)

Inserting in a table
 val insertQuery = "INSERT INTO employee VALUES("+idtext+",'"+nametext+"',"+phonenumber+",'"+country+"')"
                db?.execSQL(insertQuery)
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Inserted Data Successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Adding Fetched Data to a Spinner
val fetchdata = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM employee"
        val cursor = db?.rawQuery(fetchdata,null)
        val countries = ArrayList<String>()
        while(cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
            val country1 = cursor.getString(0)
            countries.add(country1)
        }
        cursor?.close()
        var spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        val spinneradapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,countries)
        spinneradapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = spinneradapter
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(this@SecondActivity, "$selectedItem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            }
        }

Selecting data and displaying it
 search.setOnClickListener {
            val searchcountrydata = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE country =" +"'$selectedItem'";
            val cursor2 = db?.rawQuery(searchcountrydata,null)
            val displayString = StringBuilder()
            while(cursor2!!.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cursor2.getString(0)
                val name = cursor2.getString(1)
                val phonenumber = cursor2.getString(2)
                val country = cursor2.getString(3)
                displayString.append("ID: $id, Name: $name, PhoneNumber: $phonenumber, Country: $country" +"\n")
            }
            display2.text = displayString.toString()
        }

Sorting data
sort.setOnClickListener {
            val newquery = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY employeeid DESC"
            val cursor3 = db?.rawQuery(newquery,null)
            val displayString2 = StringBuilder()
            while(cursor3!!.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cursor3.getString(0)
                val name = cursor3.getString(1)
                val phonenumber = cursor3.getString(2)
                val country = cursor3.getString(3)
                displayString2.append("ID: $id, Name: $name, PhoneNumber: $phonenumber, Country: $country" +"\n")
            }
            display2.text = displayString2.toString()
        }

Updating Data
updatebutton.setOnClickListener {
            val empval = empid.text.toString()
            val countryval = country.text.toString()
            val updatequery = "UPDATE employee SET country =" + "'$countryval'"+" WHERE employeeid = $empval"
            db?.execSQL(updatequery)
            Toast.makeText(this@ThirdActivity, "Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

DELETING DATA
delete.setOnClickListener {
        val rollval = rollno.text.toString();
        val deletequery = "DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE ROLLNO=$rollval";
        db?.execSQL(deletequery)
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Deleted Data Successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

FINDING Maximum and Minimum in the data
   maxandmin.setOnClickListener {
 val selectquery1  = "SELECT productid, name, price FROM PRODUCTS p WHERE p.price IN (SELECT MAX(price) FROM PRODUCTS)"
        val selectquery2 = "SELECT productid, name, price FROM PRODUCTS p WHERE p.price IN (SELECT MIN(price) FROM PRODUCTS)"
        val cursor1 = db?.rawQuery(selectquery1, null)
        val cursor2 = db?.rawQuery(selectquery2, null)
        val str = StringBuilder()
        str.append("Maximum Priced Product Details: \n")
        while(cursor1!!.moveToNext()) {
            val id = cursor1.getString(0)
            val name = cursor1.getString(1)
            val price = cursor1.getString(2)
            str.append("Product ID: $id, Product Name: $name, Product Price: $price")
        }
        str.append("\n\nMinimum Priced Product Details: \n")
        while(cursor2!!.moveToNext()) {
            val id = cursor2.getString(0)
            val name = cursor2.getString(1)
            val price = cursor2.getString(2)
            str.append("Product ID: $id, Product Name: $name, Product Price: $price")
        }

Finding total count
str.append("\n\nTotal No Of Products: ")
            val findtotproducts = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCTS"
            val totprice = "SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM PRODUCTS"
            val cursor4 = db?.rawQuery(findtotproducts,null)
            val cursor5 = db?.rawQuery(totprice, null)

            while(cursor4!!.moveToNext()) {
                val countprod = cursor4.getString(0)
                str.append(countprod)
            }

Finding Total Price
     str.append("\n\nTotal Price of Products: ")
        while(cursor5!!.moveToNext()) {
            val countprod2 = cursor5.getString(0)
            str.append(countprod2)
        }
        display.text = str;


I have written the complete process  to implement CRUD operations below. I have explained it with listview
DATABASE
Go to AndroidManifest.xml
add these permissions -
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

below <manifest> tag and above <application> tag

like here 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Androidstudio"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Make New Class DatabaseHelper and add the code below -
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class DatabaseHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "StudentManager.db"

        // Table name and columns
        private const val TABLE_NAME = "students"
        private const val COLUMN_ROLL_NUMBER = "roll_number"
        private const val COLUMN_NAME = "name"
        private const val COLUMN_MARKS = "marks"
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME (" +
                "$COLUMN_ROLL_NUMBER TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                "$COLUMN_NAME TEXT," +
                "$COLUMN_MARKS INTEGER)"
        db?.execSQL(createTableQuery)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db?.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun addStudent(rollNumber: String, name: String, marks: Int): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ROLL_NUMBER, rollNumber)
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, name)
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_MARKS, marks)
        val result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues)
        return result != -1L
    }

    fun readAllStudents(): Cursor {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME", null)
    }

    fun updateStudent(rollNumber: String, name: String, marks: Int): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, name)
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_MARKS, marks)
        val result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "$COLUMN_ROLL_NUMBER = ?", arrayOf(rollNumber))
        return result != -1
    }

    fun deleteStudent(rollNumber: String): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "$COLUMN_ROLL_NUMBER = ?", arrayOf(rollNumber))
        return result != -1
    }
}


In the Main Activity

do this 


package com.example.androidstudio
import DatabaseHelper
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun showAlert(context: Context, title: String, message: String) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setTitle(title)
        builder.setMessage(message)

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
    private lateinit var databaseHelper: DatabaseHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)

        val rollNumberEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.rollNumberEditText)
        val nameEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameEditText)
        val marksEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.marksEditText)
        val addButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.addButton)
        val displayButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.displayButton)
        val updatestudent = findViewById<Button>(R.id.updatestudent)
        val deletestudent = findViewById<Button>(R.id.deletestudent)
        updatestudent.setOnClickListener {
            val rollNumber = rollNumberEditText.text.toString()
            val name = nameEditText.text.toString()
            val marks = marksEditText.text.toString()

            if (rollNumber.isNotEmpty() && name.isNotEmpty() && marks.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (databaseHelper.updateStudent(rollNumber, name, marks.toInt())) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Updated Student Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to update student", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }

        deletestudent.setOnClickListener {
            val rollNumber = rollNumberEditText.text.toString()

            if (rollNumber.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (databaseHelper.deleteStudent(rollNumber)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted Student Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to delete student", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in roll number field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        addButton.setOnClickListener {
            val rollNumber = rollNumberEditText.text.toString()
            val name = nameEditText.text.toString()
            val marks = marksEditText.text.toString()

            if (rollNumber.isNotEmpty() && name.isNotEmpty() && marks.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (databaseHelper.addStudent(rollNumber, name, marks.toInt())) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Student added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to add student", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        displayButton.setOnClickListener {
            val cursor: Cursor = databaseHelper.readAllStudents()
            if (cursor.count == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No students to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            val displayString = StringBuilder()
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val rollNumber = cursor.getString(0)
                val name = cursor.getString(1)
                val marks = cursor.getInt(2)
                displayString.append("Roll Number: $rollNumber, Name: $name, Marks: $marks\n")
            }
            showAlert(this,"Selected Items", displayString.toString())
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        databaseHelper.close()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}

FINDING SPECIFIC INPUT
displayButton.setOnClickListener {
        val name2 = nameEditText.text.toString()
           val cursor2: Cursor = databaseHelper.findtotstudents(name2)
            if (cursor2.count == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No students to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            val displayString2 = StringBuilder()
            while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                val count = cursor2.getString(0)
                displayString2.append("Count is $count")
            }
            showAlert(this,"Count Items", displayString2.toString())
        }
    }

FUNCTION IN databaseHelper is 

fun findtotstudents(name: String): Cursor {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(roll_number) FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE name= + \"$name\"", null)
    }

SELECTING COUNT OF ROLLNUMBERS OF SIMILAR NAMES
MainActivity.kt
displayButton.setOnClickListener {
 
val cursor2: Cursor = databaseHelper.checkeachcount()
            if (cursor2.count == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No students to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            val displayString2 = StringBuilder()
            while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                val count = cursor2.getString(1)
                val name = cursor2.getString(0)
                displayString2.append("Name : $name, Count: $count")
            }
            showAlert(this,"Name and Count", displayString2.toString())
        }

DatabaseHelper

    fun checkeachcount(): Cursor {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT name, COUNT(roll_number) FROM $TABLE_NAME GROUP BY name", null)
    }

SELECTING NAMES AND MARKS OF THE STUDENT WITH THE HIGHEST MARKS & STUDENT WITH THE LOWEST MARKS
DatabaseHelper
    fun findmaxstudent(): Cursor {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT name, marks FROM $TABLE_NAME a WHERE a.marks = (SELECT MAX(MARKS) FROM $TABLE_NAME)",null)
    }

    fun findminstudent(): Cursor {
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT name, marks FROM $TABLE_NAME a WHERE a.marks = (SELECT MIN(MARKS) FROM $TABLE_NAME)",null)
    }

MainActivity 

 displayButton.setOnClickListener {


            val cursor2: Cursor = databaseHelper.findmaxstudent()
            if (cursor2.count == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No students to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            val displayString2 = StringBuilder()
            while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                val maxmarks = cursor2.getString(1)
                val name = cursor2.getString(0)
                displayString2.append("Name : $name, Max Marks: $maxmarks\n")
            }
            val cursor: Cursor = databaseHelper.findminstudent()
            if (cursor.count == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No students to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val minmarks = cursor.getString(1)
                val name = cursor.getString(0)
                displayString2.append("Name : $name, Min Marks: $minmarks\n")
            }
            showAlert(this,"Name and Count", displayString2.toString())
        }

DATABASE DISPLAY IN LISTVIEW
displayall.setOnClickListener {
            var arr = emptyArray<String>()
            val cursor: Cursor = databaseHelper.readAllStudents()
            if (cursor.count == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No students to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val rollNumber = cursor.getString(0)
                val name = cursor.getString(1)
                val marks = cursor.getInt(2)
                arr+= rollNumber + "  "+name+"  "+marks
            }
            var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr)
            ls.adapter = adapter

        }

ADDING VALUES TO SPINNER FROM DB
 var spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        var ls = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.ls)
        var arr = emptyArray<String>()
        val cursor: Cursor = databaseHelper.getcountries()
        if (cursor.count == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val countrytemp = cursor.getString(0)
            arr+= countrytemp
        }
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
        var selectedItem = ""
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                selectedItem = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                Toast.makeText(this@SecondActivity, selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }

Check out this answer for help on spinner - Kotlin code reports "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied"

datbase
enter code here
package com.example.labp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "student";

    // below int is our database version
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    // below variable is for our table name.
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "students";

    // below variable is for our id column.
    private static final String Stud_id = "stud_id";

    // below variable is for our course name column
    private static final String NAME_COL = "name";
    private static final String Marks = "marks";

    // below variable id for our course duration column.


    // creating a constructor for our database handler.
    public databasehelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + Stud_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + NAME_COL + " TEXT,"
                + Marks + " INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addNewStudent(int roll_no, String name, int marks) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Stud_id,roll_no);
        values.put(NAME_COL, name);
        values.put(Marks,marks);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public String display(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while(cur.moveToNext()){
            int roll_no = cur.getInt(0);
            String name = cur.getString(1);;
            int marks = cur.getInt(2);

            stringBuilder.append("Roll No: ").append(roll_no)
                    .append(", Name: ").append(name)
                    .append(", Marks: ").append(marks)
                    .append("\n");
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}

main java

package com.example.labp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText rollno,name1,marks;
    private TextView tv;
    private Button btn,disp;

    private databasehelper db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rollno = findViewById(R.id.editTextText);
        name1 = findViewById(R.id.editTextText2);
        marks = findViewById(R.id.editTextText3);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        disp = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        db = new databasehelper(MainActivity.this);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String roll_no_txt = rollno.getText().toString();
                int roll_no = Integer.parseInt(roll_no_txt);
                String name = name1.getText().toString();
                String marks_no_txt = marks.getText().toString();
                int mrks = Integer.parseInt(marks_no_txt);

                db.addNewStudent(roll_no,name,mrks);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Student has been added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        disp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String studentData = db.display();
                tv.setText(studentData);
            }
        });
    }
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Maybe try adding this to your code.
val intent= Intent(this,thirda::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("score",cnt)
            startActivity(intent)
val score = intent.getIntExtra("score", 0)


Main ACTIVITY:
package com.example.dbhelper;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText CourseName, CourseTracks, CourseDuration,CourseDescription  ;
    private Button submit;
    private DBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CourseName = findViewById(R.id.editTextText);
        CourseTracks = findViewById(R.id.editTextText2);
        CourseDuration = findViewById(R.id.editTextText3);
        CourseDescription = findViewById(R.id.editTextText4);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // below line is to get data from all edit text fields.
                String courseName = CourseName.getText().toString();
                String courseTracks = CourseTracks.getText().toString();
                String courseDuration = CourseDuration.getText().toString();
                String courseDescription = CourseDescription.getText().toString();

                // validating if the text fields are empty or not.
                if (courseName.isEmpty() && courseTracks.isEmpty() && courseDuration.isEmpty() && courseDescription.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter all the data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                dbHandler.addNewCourse(courseName, courseDuration, courseDescription, courseTracks);

                // after adding the data we are displaying a toast message.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Course has been added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CourseName.setText("");
                CourseDuration.setText("");
                CourseTracks.setText("");
                CourseDescription.setText("");

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

DBHELPER.JAVA:
package com.example.dbhelper;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "coursedb";

    // below int is our database version
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    // below variable is for our table name.
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "mycourses";

    // below variable is for our id column.
    private static final String ID_COL = "id";

    // below variable is for our course name column
    private static final String NAME_COL = "name";

    // below variable id for our course duration column.
    private static final String DURATION_COL = "duration";

    // below variable for our course description column.
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_COL = "description";

    // below variable is for our course tracks column.
    private static final String TRACKS_COL = "tracks";

    // creating a constructor for our database handler.
    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + NAME_COL + " TEXT,"
                + DURATION_COL + " TEXT,"
                + DESCRIPTION_COL + " TEXT,"
                + TRACKS_COL + " TEXT)";

        // at last we are calling a exec sql
        // method to execute above sql query
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    public void addNewCourse(String courseName, String courseDuration, String courseDescription, String courseTracks) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAME_COL, courseName);
        values.put(DURATION_COL, courseDuration);
        values.put(DESCRIPTION_COL, courseDescription);
        values.put(TRACKS_COL, courseTracks);

    // after adding all values we are passing
    // content values to our table.
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    // at last we are closing our
    // database after adding database.
        db.close();
}




    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

MAIN ACT 2:
package com.example.dbhelper;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}

}
